# A Deceptive enCRYPTion

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

Below is something which is definitely not a cipher, and lots of cryptics. Can you find the answer which will be nothing but lies?

```
EDKPMLAVBB
```

> FROM:
>   1. Either by first sphere (3)
>   2. Muscle juror almost is one who renounces belief (7)
>   3. Crooked line goes here first, then without second inform (9)
>   4. Wear broken road gift (6)
>   5. Show each class (7)
>   6. Much lasts in facial feature (4)
>   7. Scarlet Stu fails to clean again (6)
>   8. Recorder back in machinery (3, abrv.)
>
> TO:
>   ?. Bind tea with heart of honey (5)
>   ?. Compartment extractor (6)
>   ?. Environmentally friendly, corrupt C.E.O (3)
>   ?. Most audacious, crude, ending street. (6)
>   ?. Plying that regular pale  (5)
>   ?. Presently present, missing (7)
>   ?. Professional, my first formal dance (4)
>   ?. Tire drill (4)

EDIT: FROM clue 8 has been edited for specificity, sorry for the inconvenience!
EDIT 2: Really sorry to all the folks who have already attempted clue 8, it has been rewritten to (hopefully) remove all ambiguity.
FINAL EDIT: Super sorry for the dodgy clue 8. Its final form is above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The answer is:

> **CAKES**.  Each cake is a lie.

---

## Cryptics —

**FROM:**

```
1. Either by first sphere (3)
```

> **ORB**   (Either [OR] + (b)y first [B]; sphere [*def.*])

```
2. Muscle juror almost is one who renounces belief (7)
```

> **ABJURER**   (Muscle [AB] + juror almost [JURER]; one who renounces belief [*def.*])

```
3. Crooked line goes here first, then without second inform (9)
```

> **ENLIGHTEN**   (Crooked line [ENLI*] + (g)oes (h)ere first [GH]
>                 + t(h)en without second [TEN]; inform [*def.*])   **[from [@NeilW](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47986/30633)]**

```
4. Wear broken road gift (6)
```

> **REWARD**   (Wear broken [REWA*] + road [RD]; gift [*def.*])

```
5. Show each class (7)
```

> **PERFORM**   (Show [*def.*]; each [PER] + class [FORM])   **[from [@NeilW](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47986/30633)]**

```
6. Much lasts in facial feature (4)
```

> **CHIN**   (Mu(ch) lasts [CH] + in [IN]; facial feature [*def.*])

```
7. Scarlet Stu fails to clean again (6)
```

> **REDUST**   (Scarlet [RED] + Stu fails [UST*]; clean again [*def.*])

```
8. Recorder back in machinery (3, abrv.)
```

> **CAM**   (Recorder [*def., abrv.*]; back in (mac)hichery [CAM<])

**TO:**

```
?. Bind tea with heart of honey (5)
```

> **CHAIN**   (Bind [*def.*]; tea [CHAI] + heart of (ho)n(ey) [N])   **[from [@Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47985/30633)]**

```
?. Compartment extractor (6)
```

> **DRAWER**   (Compartment [*def.*]; extractor [*ddef.*])

```
?. Environmentally friendly, corrupt C.E.O (3)
```

> **ECO**   (Environmentally friendly [*def.*]; corrupt C.E.O [ECO*])

```
?. Most audacious, crude, ending street. (6)
```

> **RUDEST**   (Most audacious [*def.*]; crude [RUDE] + ending street [ST])   **[from [@Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47985/30633)]**

```
?. Plying that regular pale (5)
```

> **LIGHT**   (P(l)y(i)n(g) t(h)a(t) regular [LIGHT]; pale [*def.*])   **[from [@NeilW](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47986/30633)]**

```
?. Presently present, missing (7)
```

> **NOWHERE**   (Presently [NOW] + present [HERE}; missing [*def.*])   **[from [@NeilW](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47986/30633)]**

```
?. Professional, my first formal dance (4)
```

> **PROM**   (Professional [PRO] + (m)y first [M]; formal dance [*def.*])

```
?. Tire drill (4)
```

> **BORE**   (Tire [*def.*]; drill [*ddef.*])   **[from [@Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47985/30633)]**

---

## Solution —

> $\small\begin{array}{rclcll}\bf{From}&→&\bf{To}&\ \ \ &\bf{(by...)}&\ \ \bf{EDKPMLAVBB}\\\text{orb}&→&\text{bore}&&\text{(rotate right, append }``\text{E")}&\ \ \bf{BEDKPMLAVBE}\\\text{abjurer}&→&\text{nowhere}&&\text{(rot13)}&\ \ \bf{ORQXCZYNIOR}\\\text{enlighten}&→&\text{light}&&\text{(remove first and last 2)}&\ \ \bf{QXCZYNI}\\\text{reward}&→&\text{drawer}&&\text{(reverse)}&\ \ \bf{INYZCXQ}\\\text{perform}&→&\text{prom}&&\text{(alternate letters)}&\ \ \bf{I Y C Q}\\\text{chin}&→&\text{chain}&&\text{(encase }``\text{A")}&\ \ \bf{IYACQ}\\\text{redust}&→&\text{rudest}&&\text{(swap vowels)}&\ \ \bf{AYICQ}\\\text{cam}&→&\text{eco}&&\text{(rot2)}&\ \ \normalsize\bf{CAKES}\\\end{array}$

Comment: I'm using the same format as you, since we seem to be solving in tandem and it makes the edits easier.

Answer (score 5):

The Cryptics:

FROM:

1. > Either (OR) + by first (B) = ORB = sphere (3)
2. > Muscle (AB) + juror almost (JURER) is = ABJURER = one who renounces belief (7)
3. > Crooked line (ENLI) + goes here first (G,H), + then without second (TEN) = ENLIGHTEN = inform (9)
4. > Wear broken (REWA) + road (RD) = REWARD = gift (6)
5. > Show = PERFORM = each (PER) + class (FORM) (7)
6. > Much lasts (CH) + in (IN) = CHIN = facial feature (4)
7. > Scarlet (RED) + Stu fails (UST) = REDUST = to clean again (6)
8. > Recorder = CAM = back in machinery (CAM) (3, abrv.)

TO:

?.

> Bind  = CHAIN = tea (CHAI) with (+) heart of honey (N) (5)

?.

> Compartment = DRAWER = extractor (6)

?.

> Environmentally friendly, = ECO = corrupt C.E.O (ECO) (3)

?.

> Most audacious, = RUDEST = crude, ending (RUDE) + street. (ST) (6)

?.

> Plying that regular (L,I,G,H,T) = LIGHT = pale (5)

?.

> Presently (NOW) + present, (HERE) = NOWHERE = missing (7)

?.

> Professional, (PRO) + my first (M) = PROM = formal dance (4)

?.

> Tire = BORE = drill (4)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

```
FROM:
1. Either by first sphere (3)
2. Muscle juror almost is one who renounces belief (7)
3. Crooked line goes here first, then without second inform (9)
4. Wear broken road gift (6)
```

> REWARD (ROAD* rd; [def] gift)

```
5. Show each class (7)
6. Much lasts in facial feature (4)
7. Scarlet Stu fails to clean again (6)
8. Recorder back in machinery (3, abrv.)

TO:
?. Bind tea with heart of honey (5)
```

> CHAIN ([def] bind; CHAI[tea] + (ho)N(ey))

```
?. Compartment extractor (6)
?. Environmentally friendly, corrupt C.E.O (3)
```

> ECO ([def] environmentally friendly; CEO*)

```
?. Most audacious, crude, ending street. (6)
```

> RUDEST (RUDE[crude] ST; [def] most audacious)

```
?. Plying that regular pale (5)
?. Presently present, missing (7)
?. Professional, my first formal dance (4)
```

> PROM (PRO M(y); [def] formal dance)

```
?. Tire drill (4)
```

> BORE ([def] tire; [ddef] drill)

Comment: Since I'm not happy with the way FROM clue 8 turned out, I feel kind of obliged to tell you that your answer is correct, but backwards.